# 404 not found when calling servlet

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish

I have a simple servlet say `com.test.HelloWorld.class`

then I create these folders tree:

```
WEB-INF -->
            lib
            classes -->
                    com -->
                           test -->
                                HelloWorld.class
web.xml
```

where web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
         version="3.0">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>helloworld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
      com.test.HelloWorld
    </servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>helloworld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlets</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

after I create a .war called servlets.war and put it inside the autodeploy dir of the GlassFish server.

After I point the url: localhost:8080/servlets/helloworld but I have a 404 error.

Why? What's worng?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hit `/yourApplicationContext/servlets` as you specified that in url-mapping

for example :
http://localhost:8080/myapp/servlets

Comment: Yes, it works. So my confusion was because for me url-pattern was the same of context root and so I called servlets/helloworld. But, instead, url-mapping define a url that when linked trigger the servlet specified and the context root is automatically taken by the name of the war file...

Comment: Glad to know <!------------->

Comment: @Jigar, sorry again I wish to know if my previous comment is correct... Do I understand well? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't clearly understand your last comment, but what ever you write as URL-Mapping lets say `/XXX` then if you hit `/contextRoot/XXX` the servlet get invoked, I hope this clears up the thing

Answer (score 2):

In Netbeans services window you can right click the particular servlet and click *Open in browser*. It will run the servlet. You can find that particular URL in the address bar.